# Mockito - Is there a matcher for "value not in List"?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I currently have a mock which has specific behaviors for specific set of inputs.
Every other input should return a specific response.

For example:

```
    Mockito.when(classInstance.myFunc(Mockito.eq("Option1"))).thenReturn(answer1);
    Mockito.when(classInstance.myFunc(Mockito.eq("Option2"))).thenReturn(answer2);
    Mockito.when(classInstance.myFunc(Mockito.eq("Option3"))).thenReturn(answer3);
    Mockito.when(classInstance.myFunc(Mockito.eq("Option4"))).thenReturn(answer4);

    // Return defaultAnswer if and(and(not("Option1"), not("Option2")), and(not("Option3"), not("Option4")))
    Mockito.when(classInstance.myFunc(AdditionalMatchers.and(AdditionalMatchers.and(AdditionalMatchers.not(Mockito.eq("Option1")), AdditionalMatchers.not(Mockito.eq("Option2")), AdditionalMatchers.and(AdditionalMatchers.not(Mockito.eq("Option3")), AdditionalMatchers.not(Mockito.eq("Option4")))).thenReturn(defaultAnswer);
```

My biggest trouble is the complexity of the `and(and(not("Option1"), not("Option2")), and(not("Option3"), not("Option4")))` line.

I really hope that there is an easier way to specify a condition of "everything else" or just "not in list:["option1", ...] "

Is there a matcher for "Within a group" or something similar?

Comment: What happens if you just use `anyString()` after the other `eq()` mocks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could probably make it a bit more readable by defining the default explicitly, then 'overriding' this with subsequent stubbings:

```
when(classInstance.myFunc(any()).thenReturn(defaultAnswer);
when(classInstance.myFunc("Option1").thenReturn(answer1);
when(classInstance.myFunc("Option2").thenReturn(answer2);
...
```

Or you could use MockitoHamcrest and Hamcrest's core matchers to simplify it a bit, e.g.:

```
when(classInstance.myFunc(argThat(is(allOf(not("Option1"), not("Option2"), ...))))
    .thenReturn(...)
```

Or you could use MockitoHamcrest and your own Hamcrest matcher.

Comment: Ingenious +1. But the first way does have a drawback however. If you  modify the code to add a mock recording for the same mocked method before the `any()` matcher, it will be overwritten by the any() matcher.

Comment: I think it's debatable whether this is a drawback. A common pattern I use is to define such "`any()`" default-value stubs in a `@Before`, and then override these with stubs/mocks in the tests themselves that have test-relevant return values or which verify their parameters. This helps to maintain high-specificity, low-noise tests. I don't think this could work if the previous stubbing continued to have some effect on subsequent stubbings like you suggest.

Comment: The default mock record in the `@Before` hook method is nice !

Answer (score 5):

Why not simply use `Mockito.matches(boolean)` such as :

```
 import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

 Mockito.when(classInstance.myFunc(matches("Option[^1-4]"))
        .thenReturn(defaultAnswer);
```

As alternative you can also use `Mockito.argThat()`.
To filter out some integer values (as suggested in your comment) you could write :

```
 import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

 List<Integer> toNotMatchList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4) ;
 Mockito.when(classInstance.myFunc(argThat(i -> !toNotMatchList.contains(i))
        .thenReturn(defaultAnswer);
```

or more straightly :

```
Mockito.when(classInstance.myFunc(argThat(i -> !Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4).contains(i))
        .thenReturn(defaultAnswer);
```

Comment: Nice one! Simple solutions are always better than complicated solutions. I still think that one should be careful about using multiple specs like that, but at least your code is nicely human readable!

Comment: Thanks. That would probably work. But I actually need it for Integers, "Option1" was just an example

Comment: @GhostCat And I agree completely with you. Too much specified fixture for a mock is not straight readable and maintainable.

Comment: @GuyKhmel You are welcome. In this case just use `ArgumentMatcher`. No need harmcrest or any third library, just a recent Mockito version (the 2). I updated.

Comment: This is pretty cool what's now possible with Java 8 streams and Mockito 2. The advantage of using Hamcrest matchers however is still the much better failure messages you'll get using them instead of a straight predicate.

Comment: @ryanp yesterday Lambdas are very cool. Farewell anonymous classes for single method to implement !  In fact with Mockito 2 argument matcher you get a useful failure message : that is what it is expected what you get.

Answer (score 3):

> I currently have a mock which has specific behaviors for specific set of inputs. Every other input should return a specific response.

Is like, wrong.

The purpose of unit tests is to get you **quickly** to a bug. In order to understand what is going on, you want unit tests to be as much "self contained" as possible. You read the test, maybe the setup method, and you understand what is going on (or at least: going "into" your code under test).

Having multiple specs to cover multiple cases doesn't help with that, to the contrary. You don't want that.

Instead, you want as few specifications as possible. If your mock sees different input, and should return different results, then that should be something you do *per* test case. Not "in general", in your setup method.

So the distinct non-answer: avoid having multiple specs like that.

Comment: I love your non answers. I wrote two of them recently :)

Comment: You're right, feels like it would force you to define test cases for your test cases